# Cannot remove an external library causing the variation in library version conflict

Tags: android, gradle

[image: Screenshot of my situation]

I could not get myself out of this situation. It keeps on showing libraries version must be exact same even if there is no conflicting library in "build.gradle". Possibly because of conflicting version in the External Libraries and I can't remove one.

Comment: Hi ,Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Comment: Hey, I have uploaded the screenshot itself. There is no problem with the code. I have taken the screenshot in a way that would highlight the problematic areas. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'libraryname:version'
    }
}
```

That will force it to use a specific version of the library no matter what.  Note that this can break their library if there are incompatible changes.